# UIViewController userInterfaceStyle is always light

Tags: ios, ios-darkmode

When darkmode is enabled, UIViewControllers always use light mode.
viewController.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle is always Light but window.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle is Dark.

UIUserInterfaceStyle is not set in plist. I tried all possible settings - adding UIUserInterfaceStyle to plist, setting overrideUserInterfaceStyle for UIWindow and for UIViewController.
I logged userInterfaceStyle for different cases and results are

```
TestDarkModeViewController *testController = [[TestDarkModeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestDarkModeViewController" bundle: nil];
testController.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle //result Light
```

but for

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:testController];
navController.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle //result Dark

UIViewController *testController2 = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
testController2.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle //result Dark
```

It seems it happens only when controller is programatically loaded from xib file. Any idea what can be wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567415/uilabel-in-uitableviewcell-in-xib-file-ignores-dark-mode
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122169

Comment: thanks but it didn't help

Comment: can you share code sample you are trying, I did the same in Swift , it works as expected.

Comment: I have it only in 1 app which I can't share. It works in any other apps. What I just figured out during is that if I overrideUserInterfaceStyle = dark in viewcontroller it doesn't work, but if in viewcontroller if I do view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = dark then it works. I ended up with [[UIView appearance] setOverrideUserInterfaceStyle:Dark]; in appdelegate which seems to work. But still no idea why it doesn't work otherwise

Comment: Share the `TestDarkModeViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Set this property programmatically

```
 navController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = //.light/.dark
```

and you can also forcefully set windows property.

```
window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = //.light/.dark
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I already tried that. Only thing which seems to work is [[UIView appearance] setOverrideUserInterfaceStyle:Dark];